# Temperature and kinetic energy of a particle

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, heat-conduction

We know that heating an object makes the atoms in it vibrate. But in case of ideal gases we say that heating them increases their kinetic energy. But how does kinetic energy increase and not vibrational energy.

Comment: Isn’t vibrational energy a form of kinetic energy as well?

Comment: @FellowTraveller I guess that due to much free space present, the atoms vibrate and due to this vibration they kind of are able to move.

Comment: What I mean to say is that vibration is movement in itself.

Answer (score 2):

Ideal gases does not have vibrational degree of freedom.

When you increased the temperature of a gas, the equipartion theorem tell you that each degree of freedom receive an increase of energy. But you need to have such degree of freedom. And in the case of ideal gases, the postulate is actually that there have no vibrational degree of freedom, i.e. you cannot store energy in a vibrational mode of the ideal gas.

Answer (score 0):

The atoms and molecules of an ideal gas are considered to be point masses that do not interact with one another. Point masses do not rotate or vibrate. They only translate. Thus the kinetic energy of ideal gas atoms and molecules consists of only translational kinetic energy.

> And sir please tell when we say "heat is the vibrational motion of
>   atoms" what do we actually mean?

Heat is not "vibrational motion of atoms". What we actually means is vibrational motion, along with rotational and translational motion, is the internal microscopic kinetic energgy component of the total internal energy of a substance, the other being the internal potential energy due to intermolecular forces.  In the case of ideal gases the internal energy consists only of kinetic energy associated with translational motion of the atoms and molecules since the atoms and molecules are considered point masses with no intermolecular forces.

Heat is the means of transfer of this energy from one substance to another due solely to a temperature difference between the substances. In other words, heat is the mechanism for transferring the kinetic energy from one substance to another. Once the energy transfer occurs, it is not longer identifiable as "heat". It becomes internal energy. This is often not understood to those first introduced to thermodynamics.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Knight Yes, it is a measure of the average translational kinetic energy of the particles. For an ideal gas, the average translational kinetic energy of the particles is the total internal energy of the gas. Since there are no intermolecular forces involved in an ideal gas, there is no internal potential energy.

Comment: @Knight And since the total internal energy of an ideal gas is kinetic, we can say for an ideal gas that its internal energy depends only on temperature.

Comment: And sir please tell when we say "heat is the vibrational motion of atoms" what do we actually mean?

Comment: @Knight I have updated my answer to respond to your comment. Hope it helps.